# Configure tailwind.css on GrapesJS

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, tailwind-css, grapesjs

[GrapesJS](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs) is the best tool I ever see to build a drag and drop web builder experience. But I'd like to integrate it with [tailwind.css](https://tailwindcss.com/) which is a utility first CSS framework. Anyone can tell what is the recommended/best way to set things up to works together.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use CDN as workaround ?

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-via-cdn

I know it gives you only basic functionality of tailwind but it might be the short term solution you need to get it going.